# When I run npm run start I get this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, watchman

When I run `npm run start` I get the following error:

> ERROR watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2018-01-13T17:08:24,417: [0x7fff97db03c0] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/11reed-state: No such file or directory

I had it running fine but I had errors w/ bundling index.js file so I uninstalled watchman & reinstalled & now I have this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same ERROR, I fixed it by following these steps:

- `npm r -g watchman`
- `brew update && brew upgrade`
- `brew install watchman`

Comment: I got it, thanks. I had to uninstall watchman again but after I reinstalled it worked again.